# Gradle application plugin cannot find my main class

Tags: java, gradle

When I try to run ./gradlew run, I am getting the following error...

```
> Task :run FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class com.liljaw.desktop.CliTestApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liljaw.desktop.CliTestApp
```

My gradle project is a multi module build and is defined as followed...

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

allprojects {
    group 'com.liljaw'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
}

project(':desktop') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':core')
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.liljaw.desktop.CliTestApp'
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'LilJaw'
include 'core'
include 'desktop'
```

The file structure of 'desktop' folder which lives under the main project is as follows...

```
desktop
├── run.sh
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── liljaw
                    └── desktop
                        ├── CliTestApp.java
                        ├── JavaLogInterface.java
                        ├── PcmFloatPlayer.java
                        └── SourceDataLineTest.java
```

What exactly is going wrong, such that I cannot run my application from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed you rootProject bit different

```
allprojects {
    group 'com.liljaw'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
}

project(':desktop') {

    apply plugin: 'application'

    dependencies {
        implementation project(':core')
    }
    application {
        mainClass = 'com.liljaw.desktop.CliTestApp'
    }
}
```

The issue is that you need to have some apply plugin `application` to `desktop` project not `rootProject`.

Also the `mainClass` for `application` should be defined for `desktop` project not `rootProject`.

In your case it looks for mainClass in rootProject and fails.

I'm able to run using `gradle -p desktop run` as in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should try with adding `mainClassName = <your main class with full package path`.
You can get the details as mentioned [here](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-run-java-main#run-with-application.)

Hope it helps.

**Update:**

I tried running the same set of code as yours, and it worked like a charm. Here are things I have :
Project Structure

```
ls
build/  build.gradle  gradle/  gradle.properties  gradlew*  gradlew.bat  settings.gradle  src/
```

```
C:.
▒▒▒▒.gradle
▒   ▒▒▒▒7.4
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒checksums
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒dependencies-accessors
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒executionHistory
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒fileChanges
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒fileHashes
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒vcsMetadata
▒   ▒▒▒▒buildOutputCleanup
▒   ▒▒▒▒vcs-1
▒▒▒▒build
▒   ▒▒▒▒classes
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒java
▒   ▒       ▒▒▒▒main
▒   ▒           ▒▒▒▒com
▒   ▒               ▒▒▒▒adking
▒   ▒                   ▒▒▒▒desktop
▒   ▒▒▒▒generated
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒sources
▒   ▒       ▒▒▒▒annotationProcessor
▒   ▒       ▒   ▒▒▒▒java
▒   ▒       ▒       ▒▒▒▒main
▒   ▒       ▒▒▒▒headers
▒   ▒           ▒▒▒▒java
▒   ▒               ▒▒▒▒main
▒   ▒▒▒▒resources
▒   ▒   ▒▒▒▒main
▒   ▒▒▒▒tmp
▒       ▒▒▒▒compileJava
▒▒▒▒gradle
▒   ▒▒▒▒wrapper
▒▒▒▒src
    ▒▒▒▒main
        ▒▒▒▒java
        ▒   ▒▒▒▒com
        ▒       ▒▒▒▒adking
        ▒           ▒▒▒▒desktop
        ▒▒▒▒resources
```

Here is build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

allprojects {
    group 'com.adking'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
}

project(':desktop') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':core')
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.adking.desktop.CliTestApp'
}
```

and settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'LilJaw'
include 'core'
include 'desktop'
```

On Executing the command `./gradle run`
Got result as:

```
> Task :run
Connected to main

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

So yes I agree, mainClassName is not really necessary.

Comment: Can you give an explicit example. The link your provided actually does into no more detail than the one sentence you gave. I have tried using mainClassName, and it does nothing to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have tried doing setup as yours and shared the whole directory. Check if something is mismatching? and could create difference.

Comment: This is not accurate because my top level project has two sub projects. You are missing the desktop folder, and your settings.gradle probably does not match mine.